# Trying to implement WebviewClient but failing

Tags: android, android-webview

I saw several articles here about implementing the **WebviewClient** so that the transitions in the webview stay in webview rather than go to the browser.

When I try to run my application the webview loads but it still doesn't correct the page transition problem.  Is it possible that I need to replace the "**shouldoveride**" with the "**On Create**"?

Here is my code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    wv.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show all pages inside the `WebView` instead of openning then in the default browser, you only need to speficy a `WebViewClient`. It's not even necessary to create a custom class that extends `WebViewClient`

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign your `WebViewClient` to your WebView. Do this:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply add `WebChromeClient()`:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Using `WebChromeClient` allows you to handle Javascript dialogs!